# AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'thumbnail'

Tags: python, resize, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I  getting this error again & again I don't know where I am doing mistake

```
from skimage import io
from PIL import Image
size= 363, 310
img = io.imread(url)
image = img.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

Comment: Why import and depend on both `skimage` and `PIL`? Why not drop `skimage` and just open the image with `img = Image.open(file)`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and got the error: `AttributeError: 'Array' object has no attribute 'thumbnail'`. 
I corrected the code by converting the array returned by io's imread method into an Image object by doing the following:

```
from skimage import io
from PIL import Image
size= 363, 310
img_array = io.imread(url) # this actually returns an image array
img = Image.fromarray(img_array) # turn the array into Image object
image = img.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

I'm not sure if maybe you mis-wrote the title where it says `'Image' object has no attribute 'thumbnail'`, but this is my best suggestion. If you in fact did not write the error incorrectly and it still persists, maybe you should reinstall your version of PIL?
Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Grass but after the thumbnail, it is returning None

Comment: That's right, `thumbnail` modifies the image in place. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#create-thumbnails https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail

Comment: Have you tried other image URLs? Maybe there's something wrong with the one you've provided.